# Create a GitHub page for an existing project

Tags: github, github-pages

I have made a project on GitHub and recently added an `index.html` file.

according to the link: [creating project pages on github.io](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/)

I added an `index.html` file to my repository https://github.com/Hemal-Mamtora/HMS

I tried to go to the link http://Hemal-Mamtora.github.io/HMS which shows: "**PAGE NOT FOUND**".

How to get a web page for github project?

Comment: Did you set that in the repo setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pages.github.com/):

> Start from scratch

1. create a index.html file:

`<h1>Hello World!</h1>`

2. Click on the [Settings tab](https://github.com/Hemal-Mamtora/HMS/setting) and scroll down to the GitHub Pages section. 
   Then select the **master** branch source and click on the Save button.
3. Your GitHub page is ready at `http://username.github.io/repository`

> Also you can use a theme

1. Click on the [Settings tab](https://github.com/Hemal-Mamtora/HMS/setting) and scroll down to the GitHub Pages section.
2. Press **Choose a theme**
3. Pick one and then edit it as you wish! - **Commit**
4. Your GitHub page is ready at `http://username.github.io/repository`